# Looping over an API with a varying structure using R

Tags: r, graphite

I am using Graphite (http://graphite.wikidot.com/) to log performance statistics for various services, which we can access via an API. Each service has a few different metrics, and each metric has a few different statistics. To loop over all of them to grab the stats we want, I've written 3 nested for loops as shown below to create the necessary URL. And then it gets worse. We just introduced another level to this hierarchy because there can be more than one of each service, so they each need a unique ID. Before making this even messier, I am convinced there must be an easier way, but Googling hasn't turned up anything. Any ideas on the best way to approach it?

```
dir.current <- getwd()
dir.create(file.path(dir.current, "All Data"), showWarnings = FALSE)
dir.create(file.path(dir.current, "Charts"), showWarnings = FALSE)

# Set the grab parameters
graphite.ip <- "192.168.0.16:8080"
from <- list(hour="18", min="00", year="2013", month="09", day="18")
until <- list(hour="10", min="50", year="2013", month="09", day="19")
test.name <- "multinode"

# Builds the ugly parts of the URL.
graphite.ip <- paste("http://", graphite.ip, "/render?", sep="")
from <- paste("from=", from$hour, "%3A", from$min, "_", from$year, from$month, from$day, sep="")
until <- paste("&until=", until$hour, "%3A", until$min, "_", until$year, until$month, until$day, sep="")
test.name <- paste("&target=", test.name, sep="")

# A few variables for common statistics used.
stats.few <- c("count", "m1_rate", "m5_rate", "m15_rate", "mean_rate")
stats.many <- c("count", "m1_rate", "mean", "mean_rate", "p95", "stddev")
stats.memory <- c("total.used")

# Specify which metrics to grab for which services
engine.stats <- list("event-timer"=stats.many, "memory"=stats.memory)
journaler.stats <- list("journaler-rate"=stats.few, "memory"=stats.memory)
notification.stats <- list("notification-rate"=stats.few, "memory"=stats.memory, "reaction-tenant-one-PT4-time"=stats.many)
eventsin.stats <- list("Incoming"=stats.few, "memory"=stats.memory)
broker.stats <- list("memory"=stats.memory, "events"=stats.few)

# Specify which services you're interested in (should be above as well)
services <- list("engine"=engine.stats, "notification"=notification.stats, "rest"=eventsin.stats, "broker"=broker.stats)

merge.count <- 1
# Loops over everything above to grab the CSVs
for (service in names(services)) {
    for (metric in names(services[[service]])) {
        for (stat in services[[service]][[metric]]) {
            target <- paste(test.name, service, metric, stat, sep=".")
            data.name <- paste(service, metric, stat, sep=".")
            print(data.name) # Visual indicator

            # Download the graphs
            url.png <- paste(graphite.ip, from, until, target, "&width=800&height=600", "&format=png", sep="")
            setwd(file.path(dir.current, "Charts"))
            download.file(url.png, paste(data.name, ".png", sep=""), quiet=TRUE)

            # Download, clean and merge CSVs
            url.csv <- paste(graphite.ip, from, until, target, "&format=csv", sep="")
            data <- read.csv(url.csv, col.names = c("Data Name", "Date", data.name), header=FALSE)
            data[1] <- NULL # Cleans up the data

      # If a column has integers larger than 2^31, rewrite the data in millions.
      if (sapply(data[2], max, na.rm=TRUE) >= 2^31) {
        data[2] = data[2]/10^6
      }

            if (merge.count == 1) {
                data.merged <- data
                merge.count = merge.count + 1
            } else {
                data.merged = cbind(data.merged, data[2])
            }

            csv.name <- paste(service, metric, stat, "csv", sep=".")
            setwd(file.path(dir.current, "All Data"))
            write.csv(data, csv.name, row.names=FALSE)
        }
    }
}

setwd(file.path(dir.current))
write.csv(data.merged, "MergedData.csv", row.names=FALSE)

# Print summary of all statistics
# print(summary(data.merged))

# Print a mean and sd of all the columns
print("Column Means:")
print(colMeans(data.merged[,-1], na.rm=TRUE))

print("Column Standard Deviations:")
print(sapply(data.merged[,-1], sd, na.rm=TRUE))

print("Download and merging complete.")
```

Comment: Generalize. Write a function.

Comment: Are you using `R` simply to get mean and stddev calculations? As a sysadmin language it is a bit unwieldy (compared to `perl` or `python` or even `bash`), so you might consider doing all the fetching and csv-writing with one of those, then your `R` can be parse-compute-report.

Comment: I calculate the mean and standard deviation at the end, but the main purpose is to extract the data into a CSV file so it can be worked on in Tableau.

Answer (score 1):

I think an issue with this is that it's a big loop that keeps cbind()ing data. A better approach would be to write a function that contains all the code within the inner loop and that takes service, metric, and stat as parameters. Let's call this function "process.stat". It returns data, or whatever you wanted to cbind.

First, you need to extract the service/metric/stat tuples:

```
# One column (service)
mat1 <- data.frame(service=names(services))

# List (one entry per service name) of service/metric pairs
list1 <- apply(df1, 1, function(service) expand.grid(service=service, metric=names(services[[service]])))

# Two columns (service and metric)
mat2 <- do.call(rbind, list1)

# List (one entry per service/metric pair) of service/metric/stat tuples
list2 <- apply(df2, 1, function(x) expand.grid(service=x[1], metric=x[2], stat=services[[x[1]]][[x[2]]]))

# Three columns (service, metric, and stat)
tuples <- do.call(rbind, list2)
```

Then you would use something from the apply family to call process.stat on every combination of service/metric/stat that you want handled:

```
data.merged <- apply(tuples, 1, process.stat)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards! The Graphite URL API supports usage of Perl based regexes that allow you to query the metric tree using wildcards.

If i have the following-

```
stats.A.A
stats.A.B
stats.A.C
stats.B.A.1
stats.B.A.2
stats.B.A.3
stats.C.B.C.D.1
stats.C.B.C.D.2
stats.C.B.C.D.3
stats.C.B.C.D.4
```

Then `group(stats.*.*,stats.*.*.*,stats.*.*.*.*)` will resolve into all of them. Another interesting function is `groupByNode`.

Comment: Thanks! Quick question though: this would extract it all in one long column of data, wouldn't it?

Comment: [This](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/render_api.html#format) will sail you through all possible formats that an API query can return.